# ConEmu select startup console

Tags: windows, conemu

How can you change the default startup console of ConEmu?

Currently, when I start ConEmu, it opens a single tab with the default Windows command prompt, but I would like ConEmu to start PowerShell instead, and perhaps an administrative PowerShell console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `Startup` settings page where user can choose one of the named `Tasks` (many shells are predefined already) or choose particular startup command line.

And of course, user can define his own `Tasks` or reorder existing.

[image: ConEmu startup]

Comment: Thanks. I did actually look for it for quite a while. Only I was expecting an option that says something like "startup console" or "startup shell".

Comment: Also, I would appreciate a more friendly tone, particularly from the author of the app. Kudos for the app though :)

Comment: This app is great but setting UI has to change.

Comment: @emrah Really? And **what** do you suggest to change?

Comment: @Maximus Don't get offensive. I can say many things about it but for the subject. People including myself don't think clicking category name to open sub section. As a proof this is asked and searched. 
Even i have done this before i had to search again. 
Designers usually insert a "general" sub menu at top of sections. BTW Kudos.